# Rails: Gem Devise got attacked by spammer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise

since all other posts seem to be out of date or not presenting good solutions:

My web app uses the gem "Devise" for people to register on my website.

**Attack Description**
I noticed that every few seconds somebody send a new registration with a different email address. I don't know if every request came from the same or a different IP since my heroku logs show only the latest logs and my SendGrid account is blocked.

What are good solution to stop attacker from sending multiple registrations?

Comment: I am not sure I got it right - someone registered a lot of other people emails to your webapp?
Does he use the same IP for a set of registrations?

Comment: @borod108 : I updated my "Attack Description"

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution would be to add captcha.
Look at this:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

The second, more complicated solution would be to try to block IP addresses.
Make a table of regestration attempts and if there are many registrations form the same ip block it. (ban the user, see link below)
I would also make sure he does not know it failed, make him think the registration was successful.

https://github.com/columbusrb/conclave/issues/16